# Intel Graphic Installer 2.0.2 fails on fresh ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, package-management, intel-graphics, gpu-driver

Topic says it all. I have some issues with `intel graphic tool installation` from `01.org`. This is a fresh ubuntu installation and i double checked it's specifically for mine Ubuntu version `16.04`.

All checks complete successfully but during installation (stage `package installation`) i got error:

> Error running transaction:
>   GDBus.Error:org.debian.apt.TransactionFailed:
>   error-dep-resolution-failed: The following packages have unmet
>   dependencies:
>
> libgles1-mesa: Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but
>   17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed

Before linux reinstall i had linux `16.04.2` version and there was no issues  with updating, but now i have `16.04.3` and it seems problematic.

Is there any cure for that?

Thank you

Update: `intel graphic updater tool` version is `2.0.2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, `sudo apt install -f` and `sudo dpkg --configure -a` didn't work out well for me, but I made the following steps:

1. If you have already installed `mesa-utils` (comes with fresh installation, if you tick `Download latest updates` on ubuntu installation) purge/remove it.
2. Add PPA repository for stable `mesa-utils`:

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa && sudo apt-get update`
3. Once it's done, launch graphics tool updater.

Hope it helps someone

Update: 01.org discontinued support for Intel Graphics since Ubuntu 18.04 release and download has been removed as well. However, `*.deb` package is still available [in 01.org official repository](https://download.01.org/gfx/ubuntu/16.04/main/pool/main/i/intel-graphics-update-tool/).

Comment: Not really an answer to question at all. The Intel installer you used was only for the release version of 16.04. It can't be used on 16.04 once HWE packages are installed nor on HWE 16.04.x releases.

Comment: I have done [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/315049/cannot-install-intel-graphics-driver-on-linux-mint-18) and then added PPA. It works. Thanks