# Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS Intel Graphic Drivers

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics

I am installing the Intel Graphic drivers on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS following the instructions on the Intel website :

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-update-tool-linux-os-v2.0.2

But I am having the following error at the moment of running the tool

```
Error running transaction: 
GDBus.Error:org.debian.apt.TransactionFailed: error-dep-resolution-
failed: The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libgles1-mesa: Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 12.0.6-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 
17.0.7-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is to be installed
```

I tried to use one of the updated versions of the tool ( for newer systems ), but I have the same dependencies issues ( Version 2.0.5 ).

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue with the answer from Reborn in the following link :

[Intel Graphic Installer 2.0.2 fails on fresh ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/943647/intel-graphic-installer-2-0-2-fails-on-fresh-ubuntu-16-04)

Add PPA repository for stable mesa-utils:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa && sudo apt-get update
```

Install the new mesa drivers.

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Install the latest version of the Intel Tool

```
sudo dpkg -i intel-graphics-update-tool_2.0.5_amd64.deb
```

Now everything should be working properly.